# Deserialize json formatted string on server side

Tags: c#, jquery, json, deserialization, stringify

I am sending my array of arrays from the client to the server. Using jQuery ajax method after `stringify` like this

```
JSON.stringify({ list: FinalList })
```

and on the server side I am getting it like this

```
{\"list\":[[\"Full Name\"],[\"Select any one\",\"Option 1\",\"Option 2\",\"Option 3\"],[\"address\"],[\"contact name\"]]}
```

But I am not able to change it to the original form again. I tried using `JavaScriptSerializer` but I was not able to get the required result. It's giving me an `object`.

How I will deserialize it to it's original form?

Comment: So you tried using JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(Of T) Method (String)?? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Deserialize< T >(String)** method in [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) requires a Type parameter, which tells it which type to deserialize to.

You must have a class which has the same structure as your javascript object (has a List or Array property which name is "list"), like **MyType**. Then use **Deserialize< MyType >(text)** to get the correct **MyType** instance.

And the **MyType** class should be like this:

```
public class MyType
{
    public IList<string[]> List { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that ended up requiring a different solution. I had a complex model with several nested models within, and while I had default/parameterless constructors (it actually gives you a nice 500 error if you don't) I did not new up my nested models within the default constructor. As soon as I instantiated each of these within each of my default constructors, the deserializer was able to build my object perfectly.